# Fatal error after creating new Laravel 5 project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I created a brand new Laravel 5 application via `laravel new mysite`. When I open the site I see the following errors:

```
Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID '' is invalid in /mysite/storage/framework/compiled.php on line 1790

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging::configureHandler() in /mysite/storage/framework/compiled.php on line 1656
```

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

I've already ran `composer update` to make sure I have the latest dependencies, but I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Edit: I'm using PHP 5.4

Edit 2: It works when running via `php artisan serve` but not when using my my dev box running apache to serve the site. So it could be a local php issue on that box.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Hi. I'm using PHP 5.4.

Comment: Have you manually checked this : ' mysite/storage/framework/compiled.php on line 1790 '

Comment: I'd check configuration files. Especially the timezone settings.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal yes, It's referencing `date_default_timezone_set($config['app.timezone']);`. Which is set: `'timezone' => 'UTC',`

Comment: try to rename `.env.example` file to `.env` then **reload** apache. I think it's an environment issue

Comment: @Razor no luck, same errors occurs.

Comment: It looks like my config/app.php is not being loaded which causes issues with the log configuration.

Comment: just for debugging, try to install laravel via `composer create-project laravel/laravel mysitebis --prefer-dist`

Comment: @Razor thanks, tried that but same issue happens. I think it's because apache is not loading the .env

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue has to do with your local server settings.  I had the same issue on my local server and I set the value date.timezone in my php.ini